# understanding Spring's Bean validation

Tags: spring, annotations, bean-validation

I'm hoping someone can help me understand Spring's Bean validation.  First, if I have an annotated class,

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I can still construct an object `new User();` that would be invalid.  My question is, when/where/how should that validation occur?  Is this proper, or have I done something wrong?  I suppose I should be requiring any not-null fields be set in the constructor, but if that's the method of enforcement, what's the purpose of also providing an annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `User` object even though it is invalid at the time of the creation, because the validation is not invoked. You must invoke the bean validation on given bean either manually or using Spring facilities for validation. For instance consider this usage in Spring controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST)
public void save(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
}
```

In this case Spring will invoke validation on POST request for this handler method and will return HTTP 400 if validation fails. Internally this is taken care of by [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html).

You could also invoke validation on given object manually like so:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> errors = validator.validate(user);
```

And to answer your question, you can enforce that non null values be set in constructor. But let's consider the first example with controller for instance. It will not use that constructor, it will use the default constructor to create empty `User` object and then map the request values to its properties, so that method of enforcement would not work here.

Also, generally you might want to have an object in invalid state before it is fully initialized and the validate it before you do something with it that actually expects the object to be valid.

Comment: That makes sense.  So, spring will validate in a Controller and on `persist()` - is there another time/way to have the validation checked?  I tried putting `@Valid` in the DAO save method (for example), but no validation was triggered.

Comment: In doing a bit more reading, it looks like Spring will only validate Controllers.  I would need to implement a custom annotation to get a Service to behave the way I'd like.